# How to find parent records of all the records from the same table

Tags: sql, database

I have this table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Item]
(
    [ItemId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ParentItemId] [int] NULL,
    [ItemName] [varchar](30) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ItemId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data in the table looks like

```
ItemId  ParentItemId  ItemName
------------------------------
   1        0         A
   2        1         B
   3        2         C
   4        3         D
```

I want to find the last parent of fourth record which is first record with ItemID 1 using a stored procedure.

Comment: You want to find the ancestor (no longer having a parent)? There are some SQL variants that provide a RECURSIVE query.

Comment: Search for "recursive CTE" and your DBMS. A lot of examples over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the highest ItemId in hierarchy, which connected with given @id, your stored procedure would look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetParentId
@id int
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH rec 
     AS (
         SELECT [ItemId], [ParentItemId] 
         FROM [dbo].[Item] 
         WHERE [ItemId] = @id
     
         UNION ALL
     
         SELECT i.[ItemId], i.[ParentItemId] 
         FROM [dbo].[Item] i
         INNER JOIN rec r ON r.[ParentItemId] = i.[ItemId]
    )
    SELECT TOP 1 [ItemId] 
    FROM rec 
    ORDER BY [ItemId] ASC
END

EXEC GetParentId @id = 4
```